# Cannot pass id to click function

Tags: jquery, function

I'm really struggling trying to pass a param in a function to use in my ajax post page.

Here is my fancybox script which the eventid shows fine.

```
var fancyContent = ('<div class="header">approve booking for event id'  + eventid + '<a href="#" class="approve" id="' + eventid + '">yes</a><a href="#" class="approve">no</a></div>');
$.fancybox({
    content: fancyContent
        });
```

Get event id from link clicked

```
var getid = $('.approve').attr('id');
```

My alert here displays the id fine

```
alert(getid);
```

I then begin my click function passing the getid as a parameter

```
$('.approve').click(function(calEvent, jsEvent, view, getid){
```

My alert here is ALWAYS undefined, any ideas?

```
alert(getid);
```

Comment: Post your code in its entirety.  Its hard to assume the order of the snippets you provided.

Comment: The only argument that jQuery passes to an event handler is the event object. Defining more parameters in the function signature does not make jQuery pass more arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pass data to your event handler, you can use `trigger` method:

From jQuery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/#example-3):

```
$("p").click( function (event, a, b) {
    // when a normal click fires, a and b are undefined
    // for a trigger like below a refers to "foo" and b refers to "bar"
}).trigger("click", ["foo", "bar"]);
```

```
$('.approve').trigger('click', [jsEvent, view, 'id'])
```

Answer (score 4):

To get the ID of the clicked item you can try doing this instead:

```
$('.approve').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Comment: Or just `this.id` (javascript way).

Answer (score 1):

With your line

```
$('.approve').click(function(calEvent, jsEvent, view, getid){
```

you're **creating** a new function. You *define* the parameters of this function and like in any function declaration, the names of the variables here (like `calEvent`, `view` or `getid`), are local. So that you use the same name here, doesn't mean jQuery will ever pass that same variable to the function. In other words: when you use `getid` **inside** this new function, it's a completely different `getid` than the one outside the function.

So to get your ID, you'll need to re-assign it and do the same trick again as you did outside the function.